# Solving a linear system Ax=b with A being sparse matrix and b is a dense vector in Julia

Tags: julia, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I have a matrix `A` which is a sparse matrix stored in CSC format and a dense vector `b`. And I want to solve the system `Ax = b` for `x`. How can I do it?

Using `\` operator or `inv(A)` both don't work.
I also tried `factorize` function as suggested in the [link](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/solving-ax-b-for-large-matrix-dimesnions-efficiently-in-julia/51504).

an anyone suggest an alternative method? Using Julia v1.7.1. Also, the matrix `A` is not tridiagonal. Please check the question at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70648351/getting-an-error-when-using-backslash-operator-on-sparse-matrix-and-dense-vector) for the error info.

Comment: How exactly does ``\`` not work? It should, and it did when I tried. Same for `factorize`.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with your Julia version. Add that to the question.

Comment: I am using v1.7.1

Comment: Check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70648351/getting-an-error-when-using-backslash-operator-on-sparse-matrix-and-dense-vector for error info

Comment: Well, either this is then a duplicate, or it is an independent, in which case you should please spare the reader of cross-reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting an error when using backslash operator on sparse matrix and dense vector Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70648351/getting-an-error-when-using-backslash-operator-on-sparse-matrix-and-dense-vector)

Answer (score 2):

Define "doesn't work". Perhaps with a minimum (non)working example.

For instance, I just tried this and it seemed to work beautifully:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra, SparseArrays
julia> m = sparse(repeat(1:1000, inner=10), rand(1:1000, 10000), rand(10000));

julia> rhs = rand(1000);

julia> m \ rhs
1000-element Vector{Float64}:
 -0.8976027048792632
  1.451352807805229
  3.6881731426288042
 -0.8042571078676164
 -2.7624771730498727
```

Without more information about your particular problem, there's nothing to be said.